# How can access the uibutton ,when apply the UIPanGestureRecognizer to the same button

Tags: xcode4, ios4, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

I am new in ios development.Now, i am developing a small application with GestureRecognizer.
In my application has some uibuttons and this buttons respond to UIPanGestureRecognizer.
Now i want to identify  which button is dragging,when applying the UIPanGestureRecognizer.

if anybody know .please clear my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this would work for you

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)gesture.view;
}
```